# Flow throws an error on React element creation in a generic function

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Flow `0.53.1` emits an error when I attempt to create a React element with (supposably) good props :

```
//@flow
import * as React from 'react';

type IsValidType = {
  isValid: boolean
}

function Comp(props: IsValidType) {
  return <p>{props.isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}</p>;
}

function test<T:IsValidType>(C: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return <C isValid={true}/>;
}

test(Comp);
```

I get the following error :

```
 11:   return <C isValid={true} />;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element `C`
 11:   return <C isValid={true} />;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `C`. This type is incompatible with
     v--------------------------------------------------------------
 10: function test <T:{isValid: boolean}>(C:React.ComponentType<T>){
 11:   return <C isValid={true} />;
 12: }
     ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not a bug, though it is a bit confusing!

First, note that the code does work if you change it to:

```
function test(C: React.ComponentType<IsValidType>) {
```

The original declaration was:

```
function test<T:IsValidType>(C: React.ComponentType<T>) {
```

That original version says: "`test` takes a component that takes props that are exactly or a subtype of `IsValidType`." And it turns out the function can't actually do that.

In flow, a type like `{isValid: bool, b:string}` is considered a subtype of `{isValid: bool}`. But this function clearly can't take a component with extra props like that, because it only knows how to fill in `isValid`. So what you want to say is: `test` takes a component that expects exactly the prop `isValid: bool`. You can alternately also say "a component that expects *at most* the prop `isValid: bool`, but that gets a little trickier.

These subtyping rules are a little tricky. I have a blog post that will maybe be up next week trying to explain it better.

(Readers who find this may want to go read [the continued conversation](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4720) in a GitHub issue.)

Comment: The discussion went through on GitHub. The final answer can be found here : https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4720#issuecomment-325026124